# Simple cross platform trivia game for mobile

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Ive asked here before but I cant see it.
I really want to make a simple quiz game like LogoQuiz or so, but I cant really find a good way to platform for both iOS and Android.
I dont have Mac so I need other way to upload for the AppStore.
Any ideas guys?
Im thinking like the game will read from a text file or arraies idk.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to make it a WebApp using Angular + ionic, Polymer, React, Some other mobile responsive boilerplate code and then some javascript and json.

There's always Xamarin if your familiar with C# but its mehh.